# Finding the position and orientation of a camera given the images of three points

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, quadrics, system-identification

Here is the statement of the problem

---

Given three points $P_1, P_2, P_3$ in space with known coordinates, a camera (pinhole camera) with known focal length is used to take an image of these three points.  In the image their coordinates are $p_1 , p_2, p_3$ respectively, which are also known.  I'd like to determine the position of the camera in space and its orientation with respect to the world coordinate reference frame.

---

**My approach:**

I related the world frame coordinates and the image coordinates by

$ P_i = r_0 + t_i R p_i \hspace{10pt}(1)$

where $r_0 $ is the postion of the pinhole of the camera, and $R$ is its orientation with respect to the world Cartesian frame.

Taking pairs of points, we can write

$P_2 - P_1 = R (t_2 p_2 - t_1 p_1) \hspace{10pt}(2)$

$P_3 - P_1 = R (t_3 p_3 - t_1 p_1) \hspace{10pt}(3)$

$P_3 - P_2 = R (t_3 p_3 - t_2 p_2) \hspace{10pt}(4)$

The left hand sides are known vectors, and the right hand contains the unknowns $t_1, t_2, t_3$ and the rotation matrix $R$.  Since $R$ is a rotation matrix, it does not affect the length; therefore, we can write

$\| P_2 - P_1 \|^2 = d_{12}^2 = (t_2 p_2 - t_1 p_1)^T (t_2 p_2 - t_1 p_1)\hspace{10pt}(5) $

$\| P_3 - P_1 \|^2 = d_{13}^2 = (t_3 p_3 - t_1 p_1)^T (t_3 p_3 - t_1 p_1) \hspace{10pt}(6)$

$\| P_3 - P_2 \|^2 = d_{23}^2 = (t_3 p_3 - t_2 p_2)^T (t_3 p_3 - t_2 p_2) \hspace{10pt}(7)$

And these are three quadratic equations in $t_1, t_2, t_3$, which can be solved numerically for $t_1, t_2, t_3$.

Plugging these values of $t_1, t_2, t_3$ in equations $(2),(3)$, they become

$ V_1 = P_2 - P_1 = R W_1 \hspace{10pt}(8) \hspace{15pt} \text{where} \hspace{5pt} W_1 = t_2 p_2 - t_1 p_1 $

And similarly

$V_2 = P_3 - P_1 = R W_2 \hspace{10pt}(9) \hspace{15pt} \text{where} \hspace{5pt} W_2 = t_3 p_3 - t_1 p_1 $

Since $R$ is a rotation matrix, then it follows that

$ V_1 \times V_2 = R ( W_1 \times W_2 ) \hspace{10pt}(10)$

Equations $(8), (9), (10) $ can be solved for $R$.

Finally, from equation $(1)$,

$P_1 = r_0 + t_1 R p_1 $

Substituting $t_1$ and $R$ , we can directly solve for $r_0$.

And this is how I found the position $r_0$ and the orientation $R$ of the camera.

Comment: Should not (1) be $P_i = r_0 + t_i(Rp_i-r_0)$ ?

Comment: No.  It is correct the way it is.